# data grid view columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a filled data grid view, How do I remove columns in my grid view that I don't want?

```
private void csvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string delimiter = ",";
      string tablename = "CsvFile";
      DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

      OpenFileDialog csvOpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
      csvOpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
      csvOpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
      if (csvOpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to import the data from \n " +    csvOpenFileDialog1.FileName + "?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) ==   DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            filename = csvOpenFileDialog1.FileName;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
            string csv = File.ReadAllText(csvOpenFileDialog1.FileName);


            string allData = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] rows = allData.Split("\n".ToCharArray());


            bool header = true;


            foreach (string r in rows)
            {
                string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());


                if (header)
                {
                    dataset.Tables.Add(tablename);
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[0]);//Sequence\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[1]);//Date and Time\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[2]);//Event message\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[3]);//Event number\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[4]);//Object #1\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[5]);//doors\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[6]);//Object #2\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[7]);//Employee name\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[8]);//Object #3\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[9]);//Description #3\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[10]);//Object #4\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[11]);//Description #4\\
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[12]);//keycard\\



                    header = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(items[0]))
                    {
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Rows.Add(items);
                    }
                }
```

I need proper code that will parse my csv file into data grid view with only door, employee name, card number and date and time and sequence.

Comment: Use a `DataTable` to hold your data. Bind this `DataTable` to the `DataGridView`. When you want  to remove a column, do this on the underlying `DataTable` this will update the data displayed in the `DataGridView`...

Comment: Please help us first :), put the code that fills the grid, do I have to read all this ??

Comment: Please remove unwanted codes. so that we can help you. No one will be happy sit and read 200 or more lines of code to just find what you need.

Comment: is the datagridview bind at runtime or design time?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide a column so it is not displayed in the DataGridView:

```
dataGridView.Columns["Column you want to hide"].Visible = false;
```

You can create a new DataTable with only the columns you want and add the rows using LINQ:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Blah1");
dt.Columns.Add("Blah2");

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = i;
    dr["Blah1"] = "Blah1" + i.ToString();
    dr["Blah2"] = "Blah2" + i.ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

var Query1 = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             select new { ID = row["ID"], Blah1 = row["Blah1"] };

DataTable newDT = new DataTable();
newDT.Columns.Add("ID");
newDT.Columns.Add("Blah1");

Query1.ToList().ForEach(r => newDT.Rows.Add(r));
```

Comment: want to do it before the gridview is full, want to have no empty columns and only certain ones. I dont want to just hide the columns I dont want them there at all

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumncollection.remove.aspx)

from the link I think you could try something like this :

```
yourDataGridView.Columns.Remove(/*the column you want to remove*/);
```